Download two repos in one yocto recipe, one of the repos should be subdir
I have a recipe test.bb that downloads a given repo. Inside that repo, there a multiple folders and one of them is called lets say "lib". What I want is to add another SRC_URI in the same test.bb file that downloads another repo and puts it inside "lib" folder of the first one.
What syntax should I use and how can I do that ?

Is there anything that specifically prevents you to add lib as a submodule?
